# Is it possible to create a Maven archetype just for some packages?

Tags: maven, maven-archetype, archetypes

I was wondering if it was possible to create a specific maven archetype for just some **packages**, not an entire module or project.

For example:

```
scr
|-- main
|   '-- java
|       '-- defaultpackage
|           |-- service
|           '-- repository
|       '-- newpackage
|           |-- service
|           '-- repository
```

So I can create the `newpackage` block with an archetype.

Comment: It is not an out of box functionality for sure however why not create a custom archetype where you have archetype specific to complete project and with generic directories and customising it when creating project. That is how I do it.

Comment: I can't do that, because I need to apply this new archetype to existing projects. Since all the packges could not be created when the project starts, I need this for an incremental approach. Of course mine was a simple example, in our case, we will have more then a couple of packages, with specific class inside them.

Comment: I understand it. Let me do some research on this if I succeed I would revert.

Answer (score 1):

See [Maven / Guide to Creating Archetypes, 2. Create the archetype descriptor](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-creating-archetypes.html#a2._Create_the_archetype_descriptor):

> An optional `<allowPartial>true</allowPartial>` tag makes it possible to run the `archetype:generate` even on existing projects.

and [`archetype:generate`](https://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/generate-mojo.html):

> If the project is updated with a partial archetype, it is done in the current directory.

Comment: I'm doing what explained there, but I'm getting this error: 
`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.4:generate (default-cli) on project myproject: Don't rewrite file org.eclipse.m2e.core.prefs -> [Help 1]`.
myproject is the existing project.